# How to silently remove files in R

Tags: r

Given the following code:

```
x <- 1
save(x, file = "x")
file.remove("x")
```

The `file.remove()` command successfully removes the x file. However, it returns `TRUE` to the R console. How do I keep it from doing that?

I've tried things like `file.remove("x", silent = TRUE)`, but it seems that whatever I add to the function is interpreted as a file name, since the above returns `cannot remove file 'TRUE', reason 'No such file or directory'`.

Comment: Note that with `unlink` you won't be warned if the file couldn't be removed (you will be if you use `invisible(file.remove('x'))`).

Comment: I get the same output when using file.remove(). Can I ask what does the "TRUE" mean in this case?

Comment: @Yan - A `TRUE` result means it worked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try wrapping the call with `invisible`

```
x <- 1
save(x, file = "x")
invisible(file.remove("x"))
```